# Angular 5 - Alternative for parameterized routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My use case is this:

- In the main page, I have 2 buttons, and either of them will lead me to the same screen. When I say 'same screen', I mean exactly the same component
- At the target component, I need to know which button leads me here. So that data will be handled differently.

What I have done so far to make it work is to use parameterized routes (btn):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   //blah
  { path: 'configuration/:btn', component: ConfigurationComponent, data : { title: 'Configuration' } },
   //blah
];

export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.btnType = +params['btn'];
    });

    //this.btnType will be used to identify which button was clicked
}
```

First Button

`<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', '1']">`

Second Button

`<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', '2']">`

Problem that I want to solve:

The url is shown as:

`configuration/1` and `configuration/2`

But I want to show it as:

`configuration/HELLO` and `configuration/BYEBYE`

Can this be done via parameterized routing? If not, any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution is able to handle this no problem.
The only thing you need to do is update these:

```
this.btnType = +params['btn'];
<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', '1']">
<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', '2']">
```

to be:

```
this.btnType = params['btn'];
<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', 'HELLO']">
<a [routerLink]="['/configuration', 'BYEBYE']">
```

Without the `+`, the param will remain a string value and will be either 'HELLO' or 'BYEBYE' depending on your route.